# gcc is working, but not yielding executable

Tags: c, gcc

My C compiler was working a second ago and making executables, but I started working on a new .c file and suddenly it won't work anymore. I haven't changed anything and I'm still using the same commands, Gitbash version, etc. The compiler is still able to catch errors, so gcc works, but after calling:

```
gcc -std=c99 my_file.c
```

there is no executable called `my_file.exe`. Help sites online suggest installing additional software to fix the error, but I'm hesitant to do so because everything was working fine earlier and I don't want to aggravate the problem with additional software.

Answer (score 3):

Since you have not specified the name of the file to output, GCC will output `a.exe`.

If you desire output named something else, you must use the `-o` flag, for example:

```
gcc -std=c99 -o my_file.exe my_file.c
```

Answer (score 2):

On Unix, that compiler command would generate an executable `a.out`.  You may find that there is an executable with a default name — but I don't have Windows to check what that name is.  Guesses might include `a.exe`, `a_out.exe`, `aout.exe`, etc.

To get `my_file.exe`:

```
gcc -std=c99 -o my_file.exe my_file.c
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't specify an output `-o` flag you will get `a.exe` by default (`a.out` on other platforms),

```
gcc -std=c99 my_file.c
```

If it is working, produces

```
a.exe
```

I think you wanted

```
gcc -std=c99 -o my_file.exe my_file.c
```